# Is there any value in including SQLite in VCS's

Tags: sqlite, version-control, dvcs

Having an argument with my team. We are developing an application using SQLite and some want to add it to the repo (GIT) and some don't. Previously with RDBMS system there has been no perceived benefit of using VCS on the DB. However SQLite is a self contained file with no external dependencies so i assume, even though it is binary, that a commit of the project code + the SQLite  file will give an accurate snapshot of the state of play at that point.

I also assume that a branch and merge would work as well.

Has anyone actually done this and if so does it work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'd get more benefit from GIT's versioning facilities if you stored a dump of the SQLite database (i.e. commands required to create it) rather than the database file itself. That way you could look at the history of the dump file and see tables or data being added etc.

Comment: +1 And you can use this command to produce the dump: sqlite3 yourdatabase .dump > yourdatabase.sql

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it's preferable to include full set of dependencies in a VCS repository. This makes your life a whole lot simpler.

If you're after versioning DB schema, check out [Wizardby](http://code.google.com/p/octalforty-wizardby/).